# Composite NDVI data downloads post-2006

Tags: data

Does anyone know of sources for downloadable global composite NDVI datasets (2-week to 1 month composites) that include more recent data than 2006?  The GLCF (http://glcf.umiacs.umd.edu/data/gimms/) and USGS (http://eros.usgs.gov/#/Find_Data/Products_and_Data_Available/NDVI) composite AVHRR data is available through 2006, but in a cruel twist of fate, I need data for 2007.  My area of interest is NW Siberia, so I don't necessarily need global coverage if anyone is aware of more geographically specific data.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This was very helpfull.
But, I wonder if the data can be downloaded later, just log in later on MRTWEB? Directory wont expire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MODIS sensors aboard Terra and Aqua have vegetation indices data, including NDVI and EVI. The [MODIS Products Table](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table) shows all the available data. For both Terra and Aqua, they have 16 day data at 250, 500, 1000, and 5600 meters and monthly data at 1000 and 5600 meters.

[image: MODIS data products table]

The easiest way to get MODIS data downloaded and projected into a useful coordinate system (the default is sinusoidal) is through the [MRTWeb Tool](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/data_access/mrtweb). Here's a screenshot of it in action:

[image: MRTWeb]

I've spent a lot of time using MODIS vegetation indices data and using the MRTWeb tool, so feel free to ask any followup questions.

Comment: I just spent a few minutes running through the interface, and this looks like a great resource, dmahr. I don't have a lot of time right now to spend on the site - does the download option open up once you have selected your processing parameters and processed the scenes?

Comment: @JWallace Yep, once the processing is complete it just gives you an FTP link to download. Keep in mind that MRTWeb is an online version of the [MODIS Reprojection Tool (MRT)](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/tools/modis_reprojection_tool). As you can imagine, the online version is finnicky and sometimes is down. If it's not working, just leave it and try again later. If it goes a long time without working, call the LP-DAAC help line at 605-594-6116. Brett Lien is the guy who administers MRTWeb, as of last year.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help dmahr.  I'm going to leave this open for a little bit to see if anyone has any good leads on some other obscure Russian data sources, but I'll accept this because, well - it was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: dmahr, great answer! Do you know if this tool can be used for [MODIS MOD16 dataset](http://www.ntsg.umt.edu/project/mod16) also?

Comment: @Tomas I don't think MOD16 is in MRTWeb, but you may be able to use the regular [MRT](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/tools/modis_reprojection_tool) to reproject and mosaic MOD16 .hdf files that you've downloaded.

Comment: Unfortunately the link to the USGS website is dead.